# sklearn ValueError: X has 5 features per sample; expecting 4

Tags: python, pycharm, regression, logistic-regression, valueerror

I'm trying to do a logistic regression on "a". This is what the code looks like. I'm new to python so an in-depth explanation would be very helpful (yes, this is Frankensteined code for a presentation due in two days). It seems that the problem is rooted in the way I am retraining the data since I changed the number of variables from 4 to 5. Thanks for the help!

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/-----/Desktop/Report Data.csv")

data = data[["a", "b",
             "c", "d", "e", "f"
             ]]

data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

print(data.head())

predict = "a"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

best = 100
for _ in range(100):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

    log = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

    log.fit(x_train, y_train)
    acc = log.score(x_test, y_test)
    print(acc)
    if acc > best:
        best = acc
        with open("FMVmodel.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(log, f)


pickle_in = open("FMVmodel.pickle", "rb")
linear = pickle.load(pickle_in)

predictions = linear.predict(x_test)
for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], x_test[x], y_test[x])
```

The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SchaferJ/PycharmProjects/Model/main.py", line 65, in <module>
    predictions = linear.predict(x_test)
  File "C:\Users\SchaferJ\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 307, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\SchaferJ\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 286, in decision_function
    raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
ValueError: X has 5 features per sample; expecting 4
```

Comment: which line does this occur? can you paste the entire stack trace

Comment: "predictions = linear.predict(x_test)". i've posted the traceback